# Connection to internet while rosmaking

Tags: turtlebot, rosmake, eigen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to rosmake eigen cause it occured as a error package while compiling turtlebot, while i was not connected to internet each time i tried errors came.
but suddenely when i got connected the netbook to internet I got it worked fine and even it took only some minutes.
The error was :

```
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

[rosmake-1] Starting >>> eigen [ make ]                                         
[ rosmake ] All 7 linesroscpp: 1.4 sec ] [ eigen:... [ 2 Active 21/71 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p build
  if [ ! -f eigen-3.0prebeta3.tar.bz2.md5sum ]; then echo "Error: Couldn't find md5sum file eigen-3.0prebeta3.tar.bz2.md5sum" && false; fi
  `rospack find rosbuild`/bin/download_checkmd5.py https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/thirdparty/eigen/eigen-3.0prebeta3.tar.bz2 build/eigen-3.0prebeta3.tar.bz2 `awk {'print $1'} eigen-3.0prebeta3.tar.bz2.md5sum`
  [rosbuild] Checking md5sum on build/eigen-3.0prebeta3.tar.bz2
  [rosbuild] WARNING: md5sum mismatch (5010c6d093a4c6b59ed4804a0472bf39 != 7e048a2c20f2757a10aa8267d80b1392); re-downloading file build/eigen-3.0prebeta3.tar.bz2
  [rosbuild] ERROR: md5sum mismatch (5010c6d093a4c6b59ed4804a0472bf39 != 7e048a2c20f2757a10aa8267d80b1392) on build/eigen-3.0prebeta3.tar.bz2; aborting
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package eigen written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/sunny/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110706-225013/eigen/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< eigen [FAIL] [ 0.64 seconds ]  



''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Do we really need to be connected while rosmaking?
what is the role of internet in compiling?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10496/connection-to-internet-while-rosmaking/) by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2011-07-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some ROS packages are just wrappers for third-party libraries. When you first build them, they go out and download the code (either an archive or source checkout), unpack it, apply any patches and finally compile. That first step requires internet access.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosmake system allows to use external libraries (that are not system dependencies).

Therefore you can write a makefile that downloads a tarball, extracts it and sets it up to use with the specific package. The eigen package does this, so when you remake it, it will try to reget the tarball from the internet.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-06**:
if you clean it before yes, otherwise I do not know. Actually the download and unpack is the only thing that is done for Eigen, as it is a headers only library, so there is no compiling going on. Thus, you don't need to remake eigen for any reason (as you can't). Maybe you want to remake your code?

**Comment by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) on 2011-07-06**:
is it like this, each time i want to remake eigen it will redirect to its internet location.